# Search mails in database 

Tags: java

I want to implement searching of mails in my mail system. I have used simple procedure to search the mails in the database. I want to know the error in the query, which is given below:

```
import MyPackage.Message;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 *
 * @author ROHIT
 */
@WebServlet(name="SearchServlet", urlPatterns={"/SearchServlet"})
public class SearchServlet extends HttpServlet {

    /** 
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code> methods.
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
         HttpSession session = request.getSession();
         String receiverAddress = (String) session.getAttribute("username");
         String searchQuery = request.getParameter("SearchMails");

         Connection con=null;
     PreparedStatement ptmt=null;
         PreparedStatement stmt = null;
         ResultSet rs= null;
         ResultSet rs1 = null;

         String driverclass = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
         String dburl="jdbc:oracle:thin:@ROHIT-PC:1521:XE";
         String dbuser="system";
         String dbpassword="jaihanuman";
         ArrayList messageList = new ArrayList();
         Message message;
         String fileName = "", fileSize = "";

         System.out.print("Inside   ");
         out.print("Inside   ");
         try
         {
            Class.forName(driverclass);
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(dburl,dbuser,dbpassword);

            String sql="SELECT * FROM mail where receiveraddress = ? AND subject LIKE '%' ? '%' AND body LIKE '%?%' AND senderaddress LIKE '%?%' ";

                ptmt=con.prepareStatement(sql);

                ptmt.setString(1, receiverAddress);
                ptmt.setString(2, searchQuery);
                ptmt.setString(3,searchQuery);
                ptmt.setString(4,searchQuery);

                rs=ptmt.executeQuery();

                while(rs.next()){

                    message = new Message();

                    message.setMailId(rs.getString(1));
                    message.setSubject(rs.getString(2));
                    message.setBody(rs.getString(3));
                    message.setSenderAdress(rs.getString(4));
                    message.setReceiverAddress(rs.getString(5));
                    message.setDate(rs.getDate(6));
                    message.setTimestamp(rs.getTimestamp(7));
                    message.setAttachmentFlag(rs.getString(8));
                    message.setLabel(rs.getString(11));
                    if(rs.getString(8).equals("1")) {

                        String sql1 = "Select * From attachfile where mailid = ? ";
                        stmt=con.prepareStatement(sql1);
                        stmt.setString(1,rs.getString(1));
                        rs1= stmt.executeQuery();
                        rs1.next();
                        fileName = rs1.getString("filename")  ;
                        fileSize = rs1.getString("filesize");
                    }
                    message.setPriorityFlag(rs.getString(9));
                    message.setReadFlag(rs.getString(10));
                    message.setFileName(fileName);
                    message.setFileSize(fileSize);
                    System.out.print("Mesage" + message.getReceiverAddress());
                    out.print("Mesage" + message.getReceiverAddress());
                    messageList.add(message);

                 }
                session.setAttribute("messageList", messageList);
                response.sendRedirect("Search.jsp");
                ptmt.close();
            con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
               System.out.println( e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    finally {
        out.close();
    }
}

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 * @return a String containing servlet description
 */
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}

}
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: what is the error/exception you get?

Comment: Bad, bad headline. 'Question related to java'. Nearly everything here is a question, and `Java` is your tag.

Comment: A hint beside the point: In most cases it is a bad idea to use `SELECT *`, because the underlying database may change, without affecting your program, when an optional field is added, but if it moves to the front, your numbers will match different columns. So do the little work, and write the names of the columns out.

Answer (score 1):

Don't write

```
AND subject LIKE '%' ? '%' AND body LIKE '%?%' AND senderaddress LIKE '%?%'
```

Instead use

```
AND subject LIKE ? AND body LIKE ? AND senderaddress LIKE ?
```

and set parameter values by

```
ps.setString(n, "%your_value%");
```

**UPDATE** I've checked, and both `'%' || ? || '%'` and `?` versions are working.

Your error seems to be omitting `||` in `AND subject LIKE '%' ? '%' AND body LIKE '%?%' AND senderaddress LIKE '%?%'`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use LIKE as shown in your example.
Instead try to use this approach:

```
String sql="SELECT * FROM mail where receiveraddress = ? AND subject LIKE ? AND body LIKE ? AND senderaddress LIKE ? ";
```

and then ensure `searchQuery` is seto to `"%<query>%"` -- e.g.

```
//search for messages with subject containing "Metting"
String searchQuery = "%meeting%";
ptmt.setString( 2, searchQuer );
```